# Approach for implementing multiple character outfits in a game

Tags: ios, animation, unity-game-engine, modeling

What are some approaches for having multiple character outfits / costumes (e.g., unlockable, purchasable, etc.) in a game?

The main question is how to keep track of the animations without needing to re-animate the character for every outfit. Is an appropriate approach to have all outfits included in one large file and linked to a single skeleton? Then each outfit enabled/disabled in-game as needed?

Does anyone know how popular games do this — For example: how does Tomb Raider handle all Lara Croft's additional outfits?

Comment: Please don't close it. Although there was a similar question of this user had been closed, I don't think this question should be closed. The last paragraph might appear obvious as the developers won't reveal their code, but the remaining part is clear. I don't have experience about it yet but other devs may have encountered this problem and provide their strategies.

Comment: Hi Kay, thanks for supporting the question. Check my comment to CC Inc's answer below to see what we used as our eventual approach. After exploring public Tomb Raider assets, I believe this is a similar approach to what those developers do!

Comment: You're welcome. There is only one close vote (5 are needed to close a question) so I'm confident that it remains active :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have just one character where you want to change clothes on, and you have Unity Pro, you should look at the [Unity Character Customization example](http://unity3d.com/support/old-resources/example-projects/charactercustomization). From the demo page:

> This project serves two purposes:
>
> Having a drop-in solution where it gets really easy for you to have
>   customizable characters in your game. Having a sample project that
>   uses AssetBundles extensively, so you have some reference on how to
>   use them effectively. The project includes all the fbx files that were
>   used to generate the example assets. Please feel free to use the code
>   and artwork for your own Unity productions.
>
> Please note that this example project requires Unity Pro due to its
>   use of AssetBundles, a Pro-only feature.

There are some very good links on changing textures/mesh renderers of a character to change clothing [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/3742-Good-way-to-change-character-s-clothes...) and [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/256350/polycount-for-pc-model.html).

Now, if you want to add changable items or something of the sort, I suggest [this](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/16485-quot-stitch-multiple-body-parts-into-one-character-quot?p=126864&viewfull=1#post126864) post by `masterprompt`. It is very detailed in creating switchable objects and creating boned characters.

Another idea:

> Create one skeleton and parent the body and clothes to that skeleton.
>   Many versions of body to fit the clothes - so just forearms, full arms
>   etc - this stops problems with intersections that can happen when
>   animating the skeleton especially on devices where not all of the bone
>   weights are applied at game time.Load all of currently available
>   clothing into the same game object with only one copy of the skeleton.
>   Turn on and off the items necessary for the outfit. For this, to
>   config:
>
> The outfit sets are created as .asset files applicable to the
>   head/upper body/lower body/feet which get combined together - that's
>   going to be too much, so perhaps you just want to create a text file
>   that has the names of the components that should be on/off for each
>   outfit set. You would put this in your project, load it as a TextAsset
>   and read through each of the lines enabling sub meshes listed there
>   and disabling the others.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, CC Inc. After exploring the Unity character customization example, my artist and I tested an approach where we are keeping all character models of each character in its own file. We link each character model to a single skeleton, so then our animator can animate that single skeleton, but all different models can receive that animation. Disabling unneeded character models means Unity won't render them in memory and, from what I can tell, it won't animate any of the disabled models either.